# Regular Expression Pattern optional group depending on space

Tags: java, regex, spring-data

I am pretty new to regular expressions and I need to create a pattern that could be used in matching up different text values(cases). I can use the created pattern but it can only be used in a single case. I would like to maximize the search pattern so that it can be used to different search texts.

By the way, I am using Java 8.

**Objective:**
*Display matcher.find() by group.*

**Sample Search Texts and Expected output (Group):**

```
Search Text: "employeeName:*borgy*";
Expected Output:
-
(employeeName) (:) (*) (borgy) (*)
-

Search Text: "employeeName:Borgy Manotoy*";
Expected Output:
-
(employeeName) (:) () (Borgy Manotoy) (*)
-

Search Text: "employeeName:*Borgy Manotoy*";
Expected Output:
-
(employeeName) (:) (*) (Borgy Manotoy) (*)
-

Search Text: "employeeEmail:*borgymanotoy@iyotbihagay.com*";
Expected Output:
-
(employeeEmail) (:) (*) (borgymanotoy@iyotbihagay.com) (*)
-

Search Text: "employeeEmail:borgymanotoy@iyotbihagay.com";
Expected Output:
-
(employeeEmail) (:) () (borgymanotoy@iyotbihagay.com) ()
-

Search Text: "employeeName:*Manotoy*, employeeEmail:*@iyotbihagay.*";
Expected Output: 
-
(employeeName) (:) (*) (Manotoy) (*)
(employeeEmail) (:) (*) (@iyotbihagay.com) (*)
-

Search Text: "employeeName:*Manotoy*, employeeEmail:*@iyotbihagay.*, employeeRole:*bouncer*";

Expected Output: 
-
(employeeName) (:) (*) (Manotoy) (*)
(employeeEmail) (:) (*) (@iyotbihagay.com) (*)
(employeeRole) (:) (*) (bouncer) (*)
-
```

**Search pattern:**

```
String searchPattern = "(\\w+?)(:|!)(\\p{Punct}?)(\\w+?) (.+?)?(\\p{Punct}?),";
```

**Sample search texts:**

```
String text1  = "employeeName:borgy";
String text2  = "employeeName:Borgy*";
String text3  = "employeeName:*borgy*";
String text4  = "employeeName:*Borgy*";
String text5  = "employeeName:*Borgy Manotoy*";
String text6  = "employeeEmail:*borgymanotoy@iyotbihagay.com*";
String text7  = "employeeEmail:borgymanotoy@iyotbihagay.com";
String text8  = "employeeEmail:borgymanotoy@iyotbihagay.*";
String text9  = "employeeEmail:*@iyotbihagay.*";
String text10 = "employeeName:*Manotoy*, employeeEmail:*@iyotbihagay.*";
```

**Search texts using the given pattern:**

```
processUserSearch(text1, searchPattern);
processUserSearch(text2, searchPattern);
processUserSearch(text3, searchPattern);
...
processUserSearch(text10, searchPattern);
```

**Display found**

```
private void processUserSearch(String searchText, String searchPattern) {
    if (!Util.isEmptyOrNull(searchText) && !Util.isEmptyOrNull(searchPattern)) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchText + ",");
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("[matcher-count]: " + matcher.groupCount());
            System.out.print("found: ");
            for (int x = 1; x <= matcher.groupCount(); x++) {
                System.out.print("(" + matcher.group(x) + ") ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need to do? What are the expected results per each test case?

Comment: Using a single searchPattern only, I could use it in searching (regexp) different text values like (text1 ... text10).

Comment: Without clarification, it is hard to help you. See https://regex101.com/r/57uNcy/1

Comment: sorry for the incomplete problem, I have added the objective or expected outputs. Just want to display the matcher.find() groups values.

Comment: For `employeeName:*Manotoy*, employeeEmail:*@iyotbihagay.*`, you can't have `(employeeEmail) (:) (*) (@iyotbihagay.com) (*)`. Only `(employeeEmail) (:) (*) (@iyotbihagay.) (*)`

Comment: that is ok, it a lot closer. I tried the sample you gave and it almost works on all cases except for text9 and text10. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)([:!])(\\p{Punct}?)(.*?)(\\p{Punct}?)(?=$|,)");
private static void processUserSearch(String searchText) {
    if (!searchText.isEmpty() && searchText != null) {
    //if (!Util.isEmptyOrNull(searchText) && !Util.isEmptyOrNull(searchPattern)) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchText);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(searchText + "\n[matcher-count]: " + matcher.groupCount());
            System.out.print("found: ");
            for (int x = 1; x <= matcher.groupCount(); x++) {
                System.out.print("(" + matcher.group(x) + ") ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Note you can compile it once outside of the matching method for better  efficiency.

Use as

```
String[] texts  = new String[] { "employeeName:*borgy*","employeeName:Borgy Manotoy*","employeeName:*Borgy Manotoy*",
                           "employeeEmail:*borgymanotoy@iyotbihagay.com*","employeeEmail:borgymanotoy@iyotbihagay.com",
                           "employeeName:*Manotoy*, employeeEmail:*@iyotbihagay.*",
                           "employeeName:*Manotoy*, employeeEmail:*@iyotbihagay.*, employeeRole:*bouncer*"};
for (String s: texts) {
        processUserSearch(s);
    }
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://rextester.com/CVWD74088)

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PWvcTx/1):

```
(\w+)([:!])(\p{Punct}?)(.*?)(\p{Punct}?)(?=$|,)
```

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `([:!])` - Group 2: a `:` or `!`
- `(\p{Punct}?)` - Group 3: an optional punctuation char
- `(.*?)` - Group 4: any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(\p{Punct}?)` - Group 5: an optional punctuation char
- `(?=$|,)` - an end of string or `,` should come immediately to the right of the current location (but they do not get added to the match value since it is a positive lookahead).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to maximize the search pattern so that it can be used to different search texts.

And what are "different search texts"? Be specific!

Your problem doesn't seem specific to Java. Your current pattern contains `(:|!)`, but none of the examples suggest how `!`s may occur in the input. You use `\p{Punct}` to match the `*` surrounding the names and emails, but you have no examples of other enclosures than `*`. You don't say what the purpose of the `*`s are; are they enclosures, wildcard patterns, what?

The [following pattern](https://regex101.com/r/cKnfk4/1) seems to work for some purposes:

```
(?:employee(Name|Email)):([\w*@. ]+)
```